# how to get robot state vector from gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, navigation, odometry, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo.
I've got teleoperating car-like robot model in Gazebo. Also I have hokuyo lidar on it. Is there any simple method to get robot state vector (pose and twist) in global (gazebo) coordinate system?
I need this for publishing odometry in simulation. I've several methods like laser_scan_matching or adding special p3d-controller, but cannot i use them cause my real robot does ot have lidar and uses another control principles.
Or I need to calculate wheel-odometry like i do on my real robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43548/how-to-get-robot-state-vector-from-gazebo?/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-09-10

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do one of the following:

- subscribe to [gazebo](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo)'s `~/link_states` or `~/model_states`,
- use GazeboRosP3D plugin from [gazebo_plugins](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins) or,
- [write your own plugin](http://ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/GazeboPluginIntro) to get the specific information you need from your models / worlds.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5